# SASS throws an error for BEM syntax

Tags: css, sass, bem

I'm just trying to use the "modifier" and "element" BEM syntax in SASS.

```
.second-title{
   background-color:green;

  &--touched{
    background-color:black;
  }

  &__left{
   background-color:red;
  }
}
```

The CSS file compiles correctly but when I try to run "grunt serve" compass throws the following error:

```
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after \" &-\": expected number or function, was \"-touched{\"\A on line 71 of D:/webdev/angularjs/ang-snapscan/app/styles/mobilestyle.scss";
```

Comment: What sass release are you using? BEM syntax was fixed in the latest release 3.3

Comment: I just ran "gem update sass" and "gem update compass", it should be the latest version.

Comment: Are you using Compass as well?  The Compass stable (0.12) will force you into using Sass 3.2.

Comment: Yes, i'm using compass 0.12.6, is there any compass version that supports Sass 3.3.5?

Comment: You need to upgrade to the edge version (gem install compass --pre).

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the parent selector this way, you need to use Sass 3.3:

http://thesassway.com/news/sass-3-3-released#parent-selector-suffixes

If you're stuck using an older version, you could try this:

```
$module: 'second-title';

.second-title {
   background-color:green;
}

.#{$module}--touched{
  background-color:black;
}

.#{$module}__left{
 background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: This is messy, i just want to make BEM simpler, i don't want to overcomplicate it :/

Comment: @Kitze indeed, try type 'sass -v' to see the version of your sass, it should be working http://sassmeister.com/gist/11178675 if you have the latest version

Comment: I have version 3.3.5 ... Sass compiles it okay, the css file is okay, i think there's something wrong with compass or the grunt server.